# passing classpath to EclipseCompiler

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, classpath

In memory I build this string:

```
package consume;
public class Consumer {
    public void consume(String message){
        System.out.println(new produce.Producer().produce(message));
    }
}
```

On my filesystem I have `C:\Users\hooch\Desktop\produce\Producer.class` built from this source:

```
package produce;
public class Producer {
    public String produce(String message){
        return "THIS IS THE MESSAGE: " + message;
    }
}
```

I use `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.tool.EclipseCompiler` and pass these options:

```
Arrays.asList(new String[] {"-cp", "C:\\Users\\hooch\\Desktop"});
```

I try to compile it but get this error

```
1. ERROR in \Consumer.java (at line 4)
    System.out.println(new produce.Producer().produce(message));
                           ^^^^^^^
produce cannot be resolved to a type
```

If I have the class produce.Producer inside the project which calls the EclipseCompiler, it works. (I do not need to specify the classpath in the options then) Now the question is: how do I correctly specify the classpath so that the in-memory code can access external classes?

If I add -verbose to options, I get

```
[parsing    \Consumer.java - #1/1]
[reading    java/lang/Object.class]
[reading    java/lang/String.class]
[analyzing  \Consumer.java - #1/1]
[reading    java/lang/System.class]
[reading    java/io/PrintStream.class]
[reading    java/io/FilterOutputStream.class]
[reading    java/io/OutputStream.class]
[reading    java/io/Flushable.class]
[reading    java/io/Closeable.class]
[reading    java/lang/AutoCloseable.class]
----------
1. ERROR in \Consumer.java (at line 4)
    System.out.println(new produce.Producer().produce(message));
                           ^^^^^^^
produce cannot be resolved to a type
----------
[completed  \Consumer.java - #1/1]
[1 unit compiled]
1 problem (1 error)Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at impl.SimpleTestCompiler.executeCode(SimpleTestCompiler.java:137)
    at impl.SimpleTestCompiler.main(SimpleTestCompiler.java:155)
```

Ok, now I'm sure it must have to do with the classpath option because I swapped EclipseCompiler for javax.tools.ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() and I get the same error about the package not being resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (if you double the backslashes in the String which I assume you did because you would get compile errors in the code which invokes the compiler).

Try to add `-verbose` to the compiler options to see which files it tries to access.

**[EDIT]** As the next steps:

1. Try to run the compiler from the command line.
2. If that doesn't work, get the sources and try to debug it. There is probably something wrong with passing the classpath to the compiler.
3. I'm a little bit worried by the path of the source file (`\Consumer.java`). Try to create a correct package path when passing this virtual file to the compiler.

Comment: It tells me what it's reading.. everything on system class path. but as soon as it comes to package produce it's the same error message.

Comment: 1) Strange, I get an error in the parser. It's caused by java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9654)
2) This will take time
3) This is only the filename. I just passed consume.Consumer to it and it complained about public class Consumer not being in its own file. So that's correct. (Apart from that I have already seen it working like this, but with the producer package inside the same project)

Comment: Btw if you're interested in the whole code, I took it from here: http://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2008/07/16/using-eclipse-compiler-to-create-dynamic-java-objects-2/